# Python imaplib to gmail - Fetches only incoming emails

Tags: python, imaplib, gmail-imap

I've a simply python script which basically tries to fetch all the email from a gmail account with the following - not great at all - code:

```
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.googlemail.com')
conn.login(g_email, g_pass)
conn.select()

for i in range(1, highest_id_number):
    msg = conn.uid('fetch', str(i), '(RFC822)')[1][0]
    if msg:
        do_something_with_the_content
```

It turned out, that for some reason it fetches only the incoming emails, but not the outgoings.

How can I fetch outgoing email as well via imap?

Python: 2.7.18

Thank You.

Comment: You need to select the Sent folder to see outgoing mails   The default folder is INBOX which just has your unfiled incoming messages.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, outgoing emails cannot use IMAP. Remember that IMAP only works with Incoming connections. If you want to monitor the outgoing emails, I recommend using the SMPT protocols.

You can refer to the following documentation for more information:

- [IMAP, POP, and SMTP.](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp)
- [Email set up protocols.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229#zippy=%2Cstep-change-smtp-other-settings-in-your-email-client)
- [SMTP VS IMAP.](https://www.courier.com/guides/imap-vs-pop3-vs-smtp/#:%7E:text=IMAP%2C%20and%20POP3-,SMTP%20VS%20IMAP,-IMAP%20is%20used)

My recommendation is to create a code for incoming emails using IMAP and one for outgoing emails SMTP.

Comment: [@user2194805](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2194805/user2194805), If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)